# Android - Parse error when initializing activity

Tags: android, parse-platform

When running the activity the first time, Parte initialization (which is inside the onCreate method) goes well:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this); 
Parse.initialize(this, "...", "...");
```

Then, If I press the back button and enter again in the activity, I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
```

Which I do not really understand why, because the `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` is before `Parse.initialize(this, "...", "...");`.

Well, Ok. Then I tried to retrieve when the `enableLocalDatastore` has finihed, with `Parse.isInitialized()` method, but it is private, so I can't use it (as well as some others Parse variables I could use).

After some time, I found that If I call both methods inside a new `Thread` it works.

I'd like to know why the error happens and why It was solved with the `Thread`. Also, is there any better way to do it?

Follows the code (trimmed for the important parts):

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

Button linkParse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    linkParse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.linkparse);
    linkParse.setOnClickListener(new LinkParse());
    linkParse.setClickable(false);

    try {
        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "...", "...");          
    } catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Parse not started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        linkParse.setClickable(true);
    }

}

class LinkParse implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new StartParse());
        thread.start();
    }
}

class StartParse implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Enable Local Datastore.
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(RegisterActivity.this);
            Parse.initialize(RegisterActivity.this, "...", "...");
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Both methods should be called in a class extending `Application`. http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke these two lines of codes from the application class not from the activity

```
Parse.initialize(this, "....","....");
Parse.enableLocalDatatore(this);
```

There is no need to initialized this multiple times and global application state is meant to be in the application class.

Create a class and extend application and initialize your parse code there

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate()
        Parse.initialize(this, "....", "....");
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this)
    }
}
```

After you have created the application class. Add it to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@stringapp_name"
android:name="MyApplication">
```